# Not understanding the use of EVIOCGRAB for touchscreen devices

Tags: drivers, file-descriptors, events, ioctl, multi-touch

I am looking at a userspace library which handles touchscreen events from the Linux kernel.

The following line of code, I can't understand what it does. What is the purpose of `EVIOCGRAB` when passed to ioctl here with the touchscreen file descriptor ,and why exactly is it required?

```
ioctl(fd, EVIOCGRAB, (void *)1);
```

Google searches of `EVIOCGRAB` don't give me much i'm afraid. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`EVIOCGRAB` with an argument of 1 tries to grab the `evdev` device exclusively; if this is successful, then all events produced by the grabbed device will go only to the owning client. Strictly speaking this is not required, and in fact [`libevdev`’s documentation of `libevdev_grab`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/libevdev/doc/latest/group__init.html#ga5d434af74fee20f273db568e2cbbd13f) (which is [the library call wrapping `EVIOCGRAB`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/libevdev/doc/latest/ioctls.html)) says

> This is generally a bad idea. Don't do this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm still not sure if I understand.  "Grabbed device only going to the owning client", this means only to the one userspace application which sets it? But what about the kernel touchscreen driver, will it also go there?

Comment: If `fd` points to the touchscreen device, then yes, events produced by the touchscreen driver, for that device, will go to the grabbing application only. The default is for input events to go to all client programs.

Comment: would this also prevent a kernel driver from using it? Example being an I2C driver which gets the raw data from I2C and sends it to the fd?

Comment: Yes, the grab is supposed to be honoured by all kernel drivers as well (see [`input_pass_values`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.2/source/drivers/input/input.c#L139) and [`input_event`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.2/source/drivers/input/input.c#L433)). You *could* write an uncooperative driver which ignores the `grab` field in `struct input_dev`, if you really wanted to.